# How to install old PHP 5.5.21 on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: command-line, apache2, php, compiling

I need to install specific PHP 5.5.21 version with some extensions GD2, PDO, PDO_pgsql, SOAP, ZIP, ICONV, OPENSSL, XML, with Apache2 in Ubuntu 20.04

I would like to install PHP on defaults directory like when we install with apt-get command

Those are the steps I'm following

```
mkdir /opt/source
$ cd /opt/source
$ sudo wget -c http://museum.php.net/php5/php-5.5.21.tar.bz2

apt-get install apache2
apt-get install build-essential
apt-get install libbz2-dev libxpm-dev libmcrypt-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libxml2-dev libjpeg-dev libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libpng-dev clibcurl4-openssl-dev pkg-config libssl-dev libsslcommon-dev pkg-config libmcrypt-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libicu-dev libpq-dev libxslt-dev
/usr/local/include
ln -s /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl curl
cd /opt/source/php-5.5.21

./configure --enable-opcache --with-pgsql --with-tidy --with-curl --with-openssl-dir --with-zlib-dir --with-xpm-dir --with-pdo-pgsql --with-xsl --with-xmlrpc --with-iconv-dir --with-snmp --enable-exif --enable-calendar --with-bz2 --with-mcrypt --with-gd --with-jpeg-dir --with-png-dir --with-freetype-dir --enable-mbstring --enable-zip --with-pear --with-libdir=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-simplexml --enable-soap -with-curl --enable-libxml --enable-xml

make
make install
```

When I finish the installation, the installation locations are completely different from when I install with apt-get

In addition, PHP not working. Despite installing without errors, it seems that Apache cannot interpret PHP.

Can someone help me?